# Double timer running in fragment when fragment changed in tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer

I have implemented a tabbed activity in android. It contains 3 tabs from 3 fragments. On one fragment I have setup a countdown timer.

**My problem is:** on changing those fragments in the tabbed activity and returning to the fragment with timer via tab, **my old timer value continues but new instance of timer value is also running alongside** i.e. first set timer value shows then flips to new set timer value then first set time and so on.

The tabbed activity is same as provided from android studio with little changes to open fragments as:

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentA();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FragmentB();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FragmentC();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I have the countdown timer implemented in FragmentA as:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
TextView mCountDown;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mCountDown = view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long check = millisUntilFinished;
            int hour = (int) check / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            check = (int) (check - (hour * 1000 * 60 * 60));
            int min = (int) check / (1000 * 60);
            check = (int) (check - (min * 1000 * 60));
            int sec = (int) check / (1000);

            mCountDown.setText(hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountDown.setText("Reached");
        }
    }.start();

}
}
```

If anyone would help me then I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was on FragmentA itself. I had set the countdowntimer millisec value on the **onViewCreated() method** which was creating the problem.

So the solution would be to initialize the millisec value on the onCreate() method and use that value to start countdowntimer on the onViewCreated() method. And also used onResume() method to continue the same timer though fragments were changed via tabs. (Further to avoid reiterating code, a small method for timer was created.)

Code on FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
private long millisecvalue;
TextView mCountDown;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    millisecvalue = 1000000;        //initial timer value
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    mCountDown = view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    startContinueTimer();

}

private void startContinueTimer() {
    countDownTimer =  new CountDownTimer(millisecvalue, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long check = millisUntilFinished;
            int hour = (int) check / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            check = (int) (check - (hour * 1000 * 60 * 60));
            int min = (int) check / (1000 * 60);
            check = (int) (check - (min * 1000 * 60));
            int sec = (int) check / (1000);

            mCountDown.setText(hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
            millisecvalue = millisUntilFinished;    //update milisecvalue "VERY IMPORTANT"
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountDown.setText("Reached");
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startContinueTimer();
}
}
```

Hope this helps. If there are better ways then please tell me!